# How do I remove unwanted kernels in my 12.x machine

Tags: grub2, kernel

How do I remove unwanted kernels in my 12.x machine

```
sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-96-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-93-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-68-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-68-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-96-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-93-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-68-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-68-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation on this issue over at the wiki, see here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

If "apt-get autoremove" does not remove them, your best choice for precise might be to install the byobu package from it's PPA as mentioned on that page, to get the 'purge-old-kernels' command.

Please also note that Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) reaches end of support next month in April and is now end-of-life.  Please consider upgrading to 14.04 (trusty) or preferably 16.04 (xenial).

Answer (score 1):

To remove old kernel, first you may want to use `sudo apt-get autoremove` as this command is the default approach offered by `apt` tool to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed.

If you feel like to doing it yourself, then do it. However there are an important thing to watch for, **DO NOT EVER REMOVE CURRENTLY USED KERNEL !!!**. Did this and you're done for sure.

<sub>(To check currently kernel images, run `uname -r` on terminal)</sub>

For safer alterniative, consider try a command called `purge-old-kernels` that can be used to purge extra kernels. It will keep 2 latest kernels and the current one by default. The script is maintained on Byobu package, so install them:

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
```

Followed by `purge-old-kernels` command:

```
sudo purge-old-kernels
```